# How to pass Node JS variables into HTML file in react-native?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I am currently working on a project in which I have to render html into `react-native-webview`. This part is working fine. However the HTML is with static content, I want to insert variables into it, so that the html will have dynamic data. One thought I came up with is, transforming Html into string and adding variables like below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

class MyInlineWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    let variable = "hello"
    return (
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: '<h1>'+variable+'</h1>' }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The above solution is working however, for larger html, there must be another way to do it. Guide me.

Comment: You can try with template string.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. @Kornflexx, can you be more clear about template string?